# Get tab values from signed_completed document

Tags: docusignapi

First of all, DocuSign does not have consistent name for tabs in the document. When you convert PDF into DocuSign template, they were called "fields" which are where you could input your values such as text box, radio button, and check box.

Then in DocuSign admin console, DocuSign lists or labels them as Tags. But in the API document or calls, DocuSign uses another keyword as tab.

My question is how to get all the tab value from a signed document. There is a API call to get tab value from a draft document. It may work for a signed document too. But that API is based on recipient as well.

So if a document has multiple recipients and they all can change one tab. Then once the document is signed by all recipients, how do I get the final tab value from this final document.

The key is  there should be only ONE final document regardless how many signers. So I should NOT get the value from each recipient and guess whose input is the final one.

Comment: Yes you can do this in one API call using the DocuSign REST API - I'll post an answer shortly...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make a single API call to get all the tab values and information from a given, completed envelope in addition to draft ones.  You need to make a **GET** request to the URI

```
v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/recipients
```

And you need to include the optional query parameter `?include_tabs=true`

For instance, your call should look like:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/...123456.../envelopes/...ABCDE.../recipients?include_tabs=true

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Sample Response for a completed envelope with 2 recipients:

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "name": "Signature",
            "tabLabel": "Signature 1",
            "scaleValue": 1,
            "optional": "false",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1822485",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "88",
            "yPosition": "234",
            "tabId": "07e52952-304d-42d3-8ed2-347945e8a5bb"
          }
        ],
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "height": 22,
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "validationPattern": "",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "name": "Text",
            "value": "recipient 1 text goes here",
            "width": 120,
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "DataField1",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size9",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1822485",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "160",
            "yPosition": "261",
            "tabId": "668c1395-ced9-4b17-8ee9-f495ecbf02cd"
          }
        ],
        "checkboxTabs": [
          {
            "name": "Checkbox",
            "tabLabel": "Checkbox 1",
            "selected": "true",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1822485",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "118",
            "yPosition": "298",
            "tabId": "c767ad9a-9ab9-464d-bf4b-4dbfd811fa98"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isBulkRecipient": "false",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john@test.com",
      "recipientId": "1822485",
      "recipientIdGuid": "5cb7641f-4009-4341-ab36-7d81074e3456",
      "requireIdLookup": "false",
      "userId": "346a8395-6a4a-4044-87a4-77586d038bf7",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "status": "completed",
      "signedDateTime": "2015-03-23T19:39:39.6270000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2015-03-23T19:39:14.7770000Z"
    },
    {
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "name": "Signature",
            "tabLabel": "Signature 2",
            "scaleValue": 1,
            "optional": "false",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1827039",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "320",
            "yPosition": "234",
            "tabId": "dd733be4-6f07-4ab3-bc1f-6b46596e7faa"
          }
        ],
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "height": 22,
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "validationPattern": "",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "name": "Text",
            "value": "Sally's text goes here",
            "width": 120,
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "DataField2",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size9",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1827039",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "445",
            "yPosition": "261",
            "tabId": "7e435666-255c-4a3c-8699-be71ab6f384b"
          }
        ],
        "listTabs": [
          {
            "listItems": [
              {
                "text": "foo",
                "value": "foo",
                "selected": "true"
              },
              {
                "text": "bar",
                "value": "bar",
                "selected": "false"
              }
            ],
            "value": "foo",
            "width": 100,
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "required": "true",
            "locked": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "tabLabel": "Drop Down 1",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size9",
            "documentId": "1386280",
            "recipientId": "1827039",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "320",
            "yPosition": "301",
            "tabId": "b845dde2-ba64-4905-8400-a7b795877ef2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "isBulkRecipient": "false",
      "name": "Sally Doe",
      "email": "sally@test.com",
      "recipientId": "1827039",
      "recipientIdGuid": "43617294-9b97-41c2-8b90-bac4f40a0b33",
      "requireIdLookup": "false",
      "userId": "346a8395-6a4a-4044-87a4-77586d038bf7",
      "routingOrder": "2",
      "status": "completed",
      "signedDateTime": "2015-03-23T19:40:43.6630000Z",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2015-03-23T19:40:20.4070000Z"
    }
  ],
  "agents": [],
  "editors": [],
  "intermediaries": [],
  "carbonCopies": [],
  "certifiedDeliveries": [],
  "inPersonSigners": [],
  "recipientCount": "2",
  "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

See [THIS PAGE](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Recipient%20Status.htm) of the REST API documentation for more info on the call.